# Error: Compile Error: Loop variable must be of type SOBJECT:Account

Tags: apex, trigger

When I try to write a trigger on my  account object I am getting an error.

> Error: Compile Error: Loop variable must be of type SOBJECT:Account at line 3 column 17

My code :

```
   trigger testingTrigger on Account (after Update) {
     for(Account ca : Trigger.New){
     }
  }
```

I tried with the other custom object it works but on this account it don't. Can any one out here can help me to get the solution on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be one Apex class with name 'Account'.Please rename that class and try again.

Thanks,
Raviteja